# Ajax url segments with jquery using AJAX crawling scheme

Tags: jquery, ajax, accessibility

I am researching how to approach loading content with ajax for my web application

I notice twitter are using the google AJAX crawling scheme: (http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/)

but instead of:
http://twitter.com/who_to_follow#!key=value

they are using something like:
http://twitter.com/#!/who_to_follow/suggestions

How would I handle segments instead of #key=value in a ajax request with jquery?

any help/advice is much appreciated
Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM window object to load the full hash fragment:

```
q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

**q** would contain everything on the right side of the hash. You can then split **q** on '/' and reference the result partitions as an array. There are code examples for this here: http://goo.gl/0lJ0J